# Subclass of XMLParser crashes with the contentsOfURL initializer if there isn't connectivity, Internet or otherwise, to get the contents of the URL

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsxmlparser

I'm trying to sort out an [issue](https://github.com/nmdias/FeedKit/issues/4) where a feed parsing framework ([FeedKit](https://github.com/nmdias/FeedKit)) crashes if there is no connectivity to get the contents of the specified URL (e.g. the app is offline).

So, it works when the App is online, and online only.

Whenever I try to instantiate my `Parser` class with the convenience initializer of the superclass `XMLParser`

```
convenience init?(contentsOf url: URL)
```

The framework crashes:

[image]

In order to try and isolate the problem, and exclude some error introduced in the framework, I have recreated the issue in a clean project:

A solution that works like a charm, using a plain vanilla XMLParser of the Foundation framework:

```
let feedURL = URL(string: "http://images.apple.com/main/rss/hotnews/hotnews.rss")!

if let parser = XMLParser(contentsOf: feedURL) { // Works as expected
    print("Got instance \(parser)")
}
```

And another that doesn't:

```
class Parser: XMLParser { }

let feedURL = URL(string: "http://images.apple.com/main/rss/hotnews/hotnews.rss")!

if let parser = Parser(contentsOf: feedURL) { // Crash!
    print("Got instance \(parser)")
}
```

In the second example, all I'm doing is subclassing the `XMLParser` class. No overrides or custom code whatsoever. And it still crashes.

Am I missing something?

Thank you

Edit:

Submitted a bug report to Apple with number 28904764 and opened up a [Radar](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4946181125832704) to this issue.

I'm confident that this is a bug on Apple's end, but would prefer to be wrong and have a fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug.

However, you can override the designated and convenience initializer of `XMLParser` class in `Parser`  and implement your own logic

```
class Parser: XMLParser {
    override init(data: Data)
    {
        super.init(data: data) 
    }

    convenience init?(contentsOf url: URL){
        //return data or null examining data from url
        do{
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            self.init(data: data)

        }catch{
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

And call as

```
  let feedURL = URL(string: "http://images.apple.com/main/rss/hotnews/hotnews.rss")
  if let parser = Parser(contentsOf: feedURL!){
        print("Got instance \(parser)")
    }else{
        print("no data in url")
    }
```

Comment: Already suggested this approach as a temporary solution in the original issue https://github.com/nmdias/FeedKit/issues/4. I do not wish to provide a custom implementation of the initializer in the framework, as it defeats the purpose of the super's init. In the meanwhile, got a reply from Apple asking for the crash logs. Will update when get more feedback.

Comment: @nmdias anyway what were you trying to know  by posting a question? An alternative solution?

Comment: A solution to a problem. I guess a workaround is as good as its gonna get. I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think it was the problem with URL. I tried ur code I got the error.

```
Unable to read data
```

I tried replacing URL,

```
feedURL = NSURL(string:"http://images.apple.com/main/rss/hotnews/hotnews.rss#sthash.fuVEonEt.dpuf")!
parser = XMLParser(contentsOf:feedURL as URL)!
parser.delegate = self
parser.parse()
```

It work all fine. (I am using Swift 3)

Comment: I'm not sure you're replicating the issue. Why are you using NSURL? Is that in Swift3? And the XMLParser in your code, what's that? Where is it defined? If it's Swift 3, it doesn't seem like you're using a subclass.

Comment: Yea...its Swift 3

Comment: Are you using a subclass of XMLParser?